# BQ Switching to TIMESTAMP Partitioned Table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm attempting to migrate IngestionTime (_PARTITIONTIME) to TIMESTAMP partitioned tables in BQ. In doing so, I also need to add several required columns. However, when I flip the switch and redirect my dataflow to the new TIMESTAMP partitioned table, it breaks. Things to note:

- Approximately two million rows (likely one batch) is successfully inserted. The job continues to run but doesn't insert anything after that.
- The job runs in batches.
- My project is entirely in Java
- When I run it as streaming, it appears to work as intended. Unfortunately, it's not practical for my use case and batch is required.

I've been investigating the issue for a couple of days and tried to break down the transition into the smallest steps possible. It appears that the step responsible for the error is introducing REQUIRED variables (it works fine when the same variables are NULLABLE). To avoid any possible parsing errors, I've set default values for all of the REQUIRED variables.

At the moment, I get the following combination of errors and I'm not sure how to address any of them:

The first error, repeats infrequently but usually in groups:

> Profiling Agent not found. Profiles will not be available from this
>   worker

Occurs a lot and in large groups:

> Can't verify serialized elements of type BoundedSource have well defined equals method. This may produce incorrect results on some PipelineRunner

Appears to be one very large group of these:

> Aborting Operations. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read value from state

Towards the end, this error appears every 5 minutes only surrounded by mild parsing errors described below.

> Processing stuck in step BigQueryIO.Write/BatchLoads/SinglePartitionWriteTables/ParMultiDo(WriteTables) for at least 20m00s without outputting or completing in state finish

Due to the sheer volume of data my project parses, there are several parsing errors such as Unexpected character. They're rare but shouldn't break data insertion. If they do, I have a bigger problem as the data I collect changes frequently and I can adjust the parser only after I see the error, and therefore, see the new data format. Additionally, this doesn't cause the ingestiontime table to break (or my other timestamp partition tables to break). That being said, here's an example of a parsing error:

> Error: Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): was expecting double-quote to start field name

EDIT:
Some relevant sample code:

```
public PipelineResult streamData() {
        try {
            GenericSection generic = new GenericSection(options.getBQProject(), options.getBQDataset(), options.getBQTable());
            Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

            pipeline.apply("Read PubSub Events", PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscription()))
                                              .apply(options.getWindowDuration() + " Windowing",  generic.getWindowDuration(options.getWindowDuration()))
                                              .apply(generic.getPubsubToString())
                                              .apply(ParDo.of(new CrowdStrikeFunctions.RowBuilder()))
                                              .apply(new BigQueryBuilder().setBQDest(generic.getBQDest())
                                                                          .setStreaming(options.getStreamingUpload())
                                                                          .setTriggeringFrequency(options.getTriggeringFrequency())

                                                                          .build());

            return pipeline.run();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
```

Writing to BQ. I did try to set the partitoning field here directly, but it didn't seem to affect anything:

```
BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                .to(BQDest)
                .withMethod(Method.FILE_LOADS)
                .withNumFileShards(1000)
                .withTriggeringFrequency(this.triggeringFrequency)
                .withTimePartitioning(new TimePartitioning().setType("DAY"))
                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER);
    }
```

Comment: None of the errors seem truly BigQuery related  - have you considered pushing the messages to Pub/Sub and then setup Dataflow to get those messages into BigQuery via batch>?

Comment: At the moment, messages coming in go through pub/sub. I then have a dataflow job that parses and writes to BQ. Are you suggesting I set up another pub/sub after parsing but before writing to BQ? What would the advantage of that be? Also, normally I'd agree with you, but the only changes between the working and the broken model are the timestamp partitioned table and the required columns. Specifically, the required columns cause the first break.

Comment: Oh, ok. I guess all these error messages are related to Dataflow instead? Please add the relevant tags, and add more context to the question (including that this is a pub/sub dataflow pipeline).

Comment: Seems like Graham beat me to the tags. What other information/context would be helpful? Only thing that comes to mind would be to paste entire stack traces/error messages, but it would get messy as they're rather lengthy.

Comment: Can you share some of the Dataflow/pipeline code?

Comment: I added some of my code. The majority of the changes occurred here. The other class with changes is the parser itself, but I don't believe it has anything to do with this. I can also provide an example of my schema in Terraform, but I'm fairly confident it's correct. The only changes there are required fields and a new table/dataset. Let me know if you guys need any clarification of the code or more code snips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I found the error. I had parsing logic (a try/catch) that returned nothing (essentially a null row) in the event there was a parsing error. This would break BigQuery as my schema had several REQUIRED rows.

Since my job ran in batches, even one null row would cause the entire batch job to fail and not insert anything. This also explains why streaming inserted just fine. I'm surprised that BigQuery didn't throw an error claiming that I was attempting to insert a null into a required field.

In reaching this conclusion, I also realized that setting the partition field in my code was also necessary as opposed to just in the schema. It could be done using

```
.setField(partitionField)
```

Comment: Have you found a way to create a DeadLetter or something when the insertion fails? I think I'm having the same issue, it works fine and one field can break everything. Also, when it fails the autoscaling becomes useless and start using all the resources

Comment: I did create a working deadletterqueue. Essentially I surrounded my pipeline with a try/catch. In the catch I just routed lines (those that broke the pipeline somehow) to a separate bucket so that I could figure out why they broke things. That being said, beam is designed so that even if you have broken lines, so long as your dataflow job doesn't crash, it'll continue to process new lines independently of other failed ones. Can you share any error messages you're getting?

Comment: I have this error: `Processing stuck in step <stepName> in BigQuery/BatchLoads/SinglePartitionWriteTables/ParMultiDo WriteTables) for at least 05h40m00s without outputting or completing in state finish at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method) `. I already used the `getFailedInserts` option, let's see if that works. Could you update your answer with your latest version code?